# ¿Cómo poner el carácter arroba '@' en el Android Emulator desde el teclado físico, en Mac OS?

Tags: android, macos, teclado

Estoy intentando usar el Emulador de Android (en Mac) para probar mis aplicaciones, pero al intentar poner el símbolo <kbd>@</kbd> (arroba) no funciona.

He probado con:
    - <kbd>Alt + 2</kbd> (El de la izquierda y el de la derecha)
    - Copiando del portapapeles con <kbd>cmd + c</kbd>, <kbd>cmd + v</kbd>

¿Cómo puedo insertar estos carácteres especiales?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es algo que me intrigaba pero la única opción para escribir la **@**, es abrir el teclado virtual desde el emulador y escribirlo desde ahí.

Espero en futuras versiones, todos los caracteres ya que no es solo **@**, se pueda escribir desde el teclado.

Asegura tener la propiedad `Enable keyboard input` especificada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]